# Index out of range error which is not supposed to happen

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get these 4 decimal numbers and convert them into binary and store them into list. and I get index out of range error..
what seems to be the problem? I tried to put them in the list not using for loop too. but didn't work

```
value = [128, 12, 1, 1]
binary = []
i = 0
for x in value:
    binary[i] = bin(x)
    i += 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert them into binary"? If you want a string showing the binary representation, see my answer below. Other, please clarify

Comment: sorry , i forgot to add bin(x)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase the size of a list by assigning to indices beyond the end of the list. Use the `append` method instead.

```
value = [128, 12, 1, 1]
binary = []
for x in value:
    binary.append(x)
```

(Even better is to use a list comprehension, if possible, although that depends on what you actually do with the value of `x` before appending to `binary`. The code you show really simplifies to `binary = list(value)`.)

Comment: binary[0] = bin(value[0]) binary[1] = bin(value[1]) binary[2] = bin(value[2]) binary[3] = bin(value[3])  like this?? I dont understand why you say I increase the size of list. I was just trying to assign a new value into the list.

Comment: No; the empty list *has* no element 0 or 1 or *anything* to assign to.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
value = [128, 12, 1, 1]
binary = [bin(x) for x in value]
```

Comment: Thank you, This was indeed the one I was looking for but I think my way should work too.